# how to refresh our application or activity in android a preset time interval (eg. 5 minute)

Tags: android

I want to reload the data of an activity in a time interval like every 5 minute my activity will be auto reload. But i am unable to do this. Please help me how i can do this.?

Please give help with some example code.

Comment: google is your friend... Search after Android Timer example.

Comment: many many and many examples you can get through googling ... give some efforts first..

Answer (score 0):

If you want data to be updated then you can create a TimerTask for the time period you want. In this task you can change your data.

http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/

```
package cz.okhelp.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class TimerActivity extends Activity {
 TextView hTextView;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    hTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
    MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    //        public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
    //        Schedule a task for repeated fixed-delay execution after a specific delay.
    //
     //        Parameters
    //        task  the task to schedule. 
   //        delay  amount of time in milliseconds before first execution. 
   //        period  amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions. 

    myTimer.schedule(myTask, 3000, 1500);        

}
       class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  public void run() {
      // ERROR
     hTextView.setText("Impossible");
     // how update TextView in link below  
             // http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-task-timertask-run-cancel-android-    example/
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

}

Comment: we have use prefrences.xml file according to that i have to set

Comment: you can read your preferences and update view according in timer task.

Comment: can you please tell me in run function we have to load data or activity and how we ll set for 3000 and 1500 time seprate

Comment: Your activity is the one who will start this timer task and you need to load/update data in fun function. Have a look at this link to understand what 3000 and 1500 means. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, long, long)

Comment: can you share email id i m sending you source code so that you can put that concept i am new in android i am not understanding i have seted pref for 3 just you put second ,20second application auto relaunch please help me